# JS: what is async/await benefit when calling api?

Tags: javascript, async-await

how can async/await be used when calling APIs where the data you're fetching is dependent on the rest of the function content under it?
What if the fake API calls here pushed more names to the array?  The `updateNames` function would be called already before the api calls would be done.  Wouldn't I want to *block* the runtime in this case and make it synchronous?

```
 let names = [];

async foo() {
      
     await Promise.all[
         this.callAPI1();
         this.callAPI2();
     ]

     this.updateNames(names);
}
```

Comment: `await Promise.all` causes the flow through `foo` to wait for the completion of all of the promises associated with `callAPI1` and `callAPI2`.  Therefore, `updateNames` is only called after the the API calls are complete.

Comment: how does it differ from calling those 2 functions outside of await though?  Aren't regular function synchronous anyway?

Comment: @sal3jfc: Assuming you meant to type `await Promise.all([this.callAPI1(), this.callAPI2()])` (adding call parens and using comma separation correctly), the assumption is that `callAPI1` and `callAPI2` are themselves `async` functions or otherwise functions that return `Promise`s without actually doing the work synchronously/eagerly. If they are doing work synchronously/eagerly, then it's done before you `await`, and if they are doing it asynchronously, the `await` blocks the current task until they're done. Either way, `updateNames` doesn't get called until they're completely finished.

Comment: If one or both of `callAPI1` and `callAPI2` return promises, then the `await Promise.all` (or some variant) is needed.  If neither return promises, then you don't need `foo` to be `async`, and you can make the API calls just like any other statement.

Answer (score 1):

> What if the fake API calls here pushed more names to the array? The updateNames function would be called already before the api calls would be done.

`updateNames` would not be called until both of the `callAPI#` functions completed; the `await` makes the code block (yielding control back to the event loop) until both promises (explicitly created or implicit when the functions are `async` themselves) complete.

If the functions in question don't return promises, executing synchronously/eagerly, then the `await Promise.all([...])` is pointless (there were no promises involved), but there's still no risk of `updateNames` being called before the `callAPI#` calls finish; either:

1. `callAPI#` returns a promise (in which case `await` blocks the current task until they complete, returning control to the event loop while it waits), or
2. `callAPI#` does not return a promise and all the work is done immediately

and in either case, you can't get to `updateNames` before they finish.

> Wouldn't I want to *block* the runtime in this case and make it synchronous?

You *are* blocking the current function call/task with the `await`. *Other* tasks scheduled on the event loop can run while the `await` is still blocked though, and that's the advantage to async processing. *Every* apparently asynchronous thing in JavaScript is sharing that event loop, and if you completely blocked (rather than `await`ing an async call), none of them could run. This means, for example:

1. `setTimeout`/`setInterval` calls don't fire
2. UI drawing operations don't occur
3. User input is blocked
4. All events and observer handling code is deferred

Truly synchronous calls would make *all* of that (and more) wait until the entirety of `foo` completed. This is why async code is sometimes referred to as "cooperative multitasking"; control is never wrested away from the current task without its consent like you'd see in multithreaded code, instead control is handed back to the event loop voluntarily (via `await`) whenever a task is blocked waiting on asynchronous processing, or when the task completes. When the async task has a result, it waits for the event loop to hand control back to it, then continues where it left off.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `this.updateNames` will be executed after your API calls are resolved because you have the `await` keyword and it is the same as doing:

```
Promise.all([call1(), call2()]).then(() => { this.updateNames() })
```

If you have any doubt you can always try by simulating an API call with a promisified `setTimeout` and some `console.log`:

```js
const simulateAsync = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("resolved");
      resolve();
    }, 100);
  });
};

async function test() {
  await Promise.all([simulateAsync(), simulateAsync()]);

  console.log("after");
}

test();
```